# Empty SignatureValue and DigestValue in SOAP Request using Wss4jSecurityInterceptor

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-ws

I am updating the client of an existing SOAP webservice since the service provider has made some changes to thier security headers in the request.

The requirement is to digitally sign the Timestamp which should be present in the request header and the body should not be digitally signed. I am using XML config to create my SOAP request header and digitally sign the Timestamp.

I am basically using org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor as an interceptor. The problem is that Timestamp gets created in the request header however the SignatureValue and DigestValue tags are empty

I have referred https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/security.html#security-wss4j-digital-signatures

**Versions**:
Spring-ws-core --> 2.0.0.RELEASE
spring-ws-security --> 2.0.0.RELEASE

```
  <bean id="wsClientSecurityInterceptor"    class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
               <property name="securementActions" value="Timestamp Signature"/>
               <property name="securementSignatureKeyIdentifier" value="DirectReference" />
               <property name="securementUsername" value="username" />
               <property name="securementPassword" value="keystorepassword" />
               <property name="securementSignatureCrypto" ref="clientCrypto"/>
               <property name="securementSignatureUser" value="username" />
               <property name="securementSignatureParts" value="{}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd}Timestamp"/>
  </bean>
  <bean id="clientCrypto" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.support.CryptoFactoryBean">
        <property name="keyStorePassword" value="keystorepassword" />
        <property name="keyStoreLocation" value="file:${key.store.location}"/>
        <property name="keyStoreType" value="jks" />
        <property name="keyStoreProvider" value="IBMJCE" />
</bean>
```

Though the timestamp gets added to the wsse:Security element in the header, the DigestValue and SignatureValue elements belonging to the xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" namespace are always empty

This does not happen if I only sign the Body

I also tried using another Interceptor XwsSecurityInterceptor but that does not work without the Wss4jSecurityInterceptor and gives me the same result when used with Wss4jSecurityInterceptor

```
<bean id="xwsSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.XwsSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="policyConfiguration" value="classpath:securityPolicy.xml"/>
         <property name="callbackHandlers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="keyStoreHandler"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

     <bean id="keyStoreHandler" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.callback.KeyStoreCallbackHandler">
        <property name="keyStore" ref="keyStore"/>
        <property name="privateKeyPassword" value="keystorepassword"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="keyStore" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.support.KeyStoreFactoryBean">
        <property name="location" value="file:${key.store.location}"/>
        <property name="password" value="keystorepassword"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: I am using Websphere 8.5.5

Comment: Deployed the same application on Apache Tomcat 8.0.50 and the signature does get populated. I can now narrow down the issue to be with WAS 8.5.5. If anyone has faced this issue earlier please let me know

Answer (score 0):

After referring a number of IBM support posts, I have finally come to the solution and have received a QA signoff too on the implementation. I had to replace all my spring mvc config for creating SSL context with configurations on the WAS server itself.You can configure all this using either scripts or using the WAS console manually.

Steps:

- Add an entry to ur applications web.xml.Please refer this post https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twbs_jaxwsclientdd.html
- The link below will give you a step by step guide as to how to configure the request payload to have a signed timestamp on WAS server.
  http://pglezen.github.io/was-config/html/signts.html#sec.signts.keystores.consumer 
  It basically focusses on :

  - Policy Set Creation:This will Specify the element or elements to be signed or encrypted in this message part.In our case its the timestamp in the header
  - Client Policy Set Bindings. If you are the provider you have to refer the provider Policy set bindings section.This involves creation of truststore and keystore required to configure your SSL context. Also has configurations for any proxy settings that you might require.
  - Finally take a JNDI reference of the service whereever you need to call a particular operation in the service.Refer https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twbs_jaxwsclientdd.html

Once this done, Simply navigate to Services--> Service Clients and you should have your service refs visible there. You should now attach the Policy set and the bindings created above to the Service client references created in WAS due to point 1 above.You might have to write a script to attach the polict set and binding since after deployment you dont want to do this step manually

Please note: this solution came into picture sicne the version of WAS 8.5.5.16,spring -3.0.5.RELEASE and spring-ws-2.0.0.RELEASE did not support signing of timestamp in the request payload of the SOAP service request. Hope this helps someone !!